# Converting WebClient to Async method in Maui or making it more streamlined

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, maui, memorystream

I have a fairly functional (but pretty poor) example of what I want to do, but i'm struggling to make it more efficient.

Basically, I have a MAUI project. It pulls in data from a mysql database including a path to a windows share to a PDF document. I then use some logic to replace the mapped drive letter to the http server path so I can download the PDF file.

```
private ImageSource ConvertPDF(string pathtopdf)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Firing CONVERTPDF SCRIPT");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pathtopdf);

    string pdfpathcorr = pathtopdf.Replace(@"Y:\", @"http://192.168.0.72:8080/E%3A/");
    string pdfpathcorr2 = pdfpathcorr.Replace(@"\", "/");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Corrected URL STRING = " + pdfpathcorr2);

    WebClient MyWebClient = new WebClient();
    byte[] BytesFile = MyWebClient.DownloadData(pdfpathcorr2);
    MemoryStream iStream = new MemoryStream(BytesFile);
    PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument(iStream);
    PdfRendererSettings settings = new PdfRendererSettings();
    settings.DpiX = 10;
    settings.DpiY = 10;
    Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
    PdfPageRenderer renderer = new PdfPageRenderer(document.Pages[0]);
    renderer.ConvertPageToImage(ms, PdfPageImageFormat.Png, settings);
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms);
}
```

This is then plugged into this:

```
private void LoadDBData()
{
    using var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=servername;User ID=usrname;Password=pwdhere;Database=tabnamehere");
    connection.Open();
    using var command = new MySqlCommand("Select ID, Path, Descr, DONum, CustOrd, PDFPath From `table`;", connection);
    using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {       
        Itmnew.Add(new workordlist { id = reader.GetInt32(0), Path = reader.GetString(1), Descr = reader.GetString(2), Custord = reader.GetString(4), PDFPath = ConvertPDFASYNCAsync(reader.GetString(5))});
        //Items.Add
    }
}
```

This does work, but it's very clunky and while it is fairly operational on windows, It really struggles on Android, it does work. But 10 records takes a good few minutes to load, which will not go down well.

I am trying to look into async methods, but i don't have much experience with this. Looks like httpclient is the prefered option. However, how can I return an image source from an async task? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Please see the code that doesn't work, what should I return? I'd return a bitmapimage, but there is no such thing in MAUI?

```
////code not working
private async Task<Image> ConvertPDFASYNCAsync(string pathtopdf)
{
    string pdfpathcorr = pathtopdf.Replace(@"Y:\", @"http://192.168.0.72:8080/E%3A/");
    string pdfpathcorr2 = pdfpathcorr.Replace(@"\", "/");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Corrected URL STRING = " + pdfpathcorr2);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(pdfpathcorr2))
        {
            using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument(streamToReadFrom);
                PdfRendererSettings settings = new PdfRendererSettings();
                settings.DpiX = 10;
                settings.DpiY = 10;
                Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
                PdfPageRenderer renderer = new PdfPageRenderer(document.Pages[0]);
                renderer.ConvertPageToImage(ms, PdfPageImageFormat.Png, settings);
                ms.Position = 0;
               //return ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms);
               //return 
                //what can i return?
               }
           }
       }
}
```

Or, any other ideas how i can accomplish something similar? I've tried using SMB to directly access the windows share, but this was even more complicated. http was much easier.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: personally, I'd probably write the resulting image to a file and return the file path

Comment: Side note - please don’t use the HttpClient in a using. It’s a special case and should be the same instance throughout the application

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. How should the httpclient be used? I’ve been looking for examples online and most seem to use it in a using. I will investigate saving an image, I thought that would slow things down. I’m trying to return up to 20 images in a list, I don’t mind a short delay, but not as long as I’m getting at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

At first, the return type of the method `ConvertPDFASYNCAsync` is `Task<Image>`, so you can return an Image such as:

```
using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument(streamToReadFrom);
            PdfRendererSettings settings = new PdfRendererSettings();
            settings.DpiX = 10;
            settings.DpiY = 10;
            Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
            PdfPageRenderer renderer = new PdfPageRenderer(document.Pages[0]);
            renderer.ConvertPageToImage(ms, PdfPageImageFormat.Png, settings);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return new Image(){Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms)};
           }
```

This will return an Image control. You can also try to change the method's return type as `Task<ImageSource>` or `ImageSource` and `return ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms);`

In addtion, just as Jason said, you can try to download the image to the local device and use it. Or you can also load the image from the URL such as `Image image = new Image(){Source = "the image's url"};`.

> I’m trying to return up to 20 images in a list

You don't need to return the 20 images once, you can return the few images(maybe 10 or less) which you want to show in the screen and then return the rest images when the appliction has showed the front part images or the use scrolls the image list.

Comment: Ooh that is some very nice code thank you! Also like the idea of only rendering first page of images… I will give it a go tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. I'm looking forward to your reply. @AndrewTaylor

Comment: I didn't have much luck with the async method, perhaps I was doing something wrong. I tried changing `PdfPath = ConvertPDF(reader.GetString(5))` to `PdfPath = ConvertPDFAsync(reader.GetString(5)).Result()` however, this didn't actually work, when debugging it just hung and didn't load the images.

Also, how would I go about only pulling say 10 images until the listview is scrolled?

The current code I have seems to block and wait while all images are loaded into memory, which is causing the delay. Even having the images loading like on a webpage would be great.

Comment: You can try to use multithread instead of async method to return the result. In addition, you can return 10 image control and then use the result in the page.cs. @AndrewTaylor

Comment: also, when I set `aindic.IsRunning = true;`
`LoadDBData();` it doesn't display the activity indicator until the loaddbdata call has finished, why is this? I thought it would work in order - this is just a private void, not async.

Comment: The cause may be that these codes are all run in the main thread, and the UI changed also need the main thread to do that. There is no code, I can't give a sure cause. @AndrewTaylor

Comment: I'm struggling to understand a concept. I've split the code up so that the list is populated, and then the display updated (without images), then there's a second process which updates the list to include the image source. But, this is still running and the displaying all the images in one go. I would like it to display a loading image in all rows, then replace this with each image one by one, is this possible?

Comment: Did you try to put the front 10(or less) images in the listview and render it. And then display the listview before getting the rest images. @AndrewTaylor

Comment: thanks for your help. Looks like I was missing something very simple - background worker. wow.... what a really amazing feature! Got to love Microsoft.... I take it all back :D